# T-SQL help in generating report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named AES Which have the following values:

```
Visitid_fk.         AE.              Med
1.                 Headache.      Aspirin
1.                 Nausea.          Null
3.                 Headache.     Tylenol
4.                 High BP.         Null
4.                 Heartburn.      Zantac
7.                 High BP.          Norvasc
```

I want to select the visit ids who never had a headache. I am writing below query:

```
Select visitid_fk from AEs Where AE != 'Headache'
```

It is returning:

```
1
4
4
7
```

Where in the visitid 1 has had headache once. Note that there are two entries for visitid 1.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected result

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is use a left join with a derived table:

```
SELECT Visitid_fk, AE, Med
FROM AES t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Visitid_fk
    FROM AES 
    WHERE AE = 'Headache'
) t2 ON t1.Visitid_fk = t2.Visitid_fk
WHERE t2.Visitid_fk IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Visitid_fk
from
yourtable t1
where not exists(
select 1 from yourtable t2 where t1.Visitid_fk=t2.Visitid_fk
and t1.AE='headache')
```

Comment: Thanks again Gordon, God bless.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select visitid_fk
from aes
group by visitid_fk
having sum(case when ae = 'Headache' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of headaches.  The `= 0` specifies that there are none.

Alternatively, you can use `not exists` (or something similar).  I would recommend using the `visitors` table (or whatever the foreign key points to):

```
select v.*
from visitors v
where not exists (select 1
                  from aes
                  where aes.visitorid_fk = v.visitorid and
                        aes.ae = 'Headache'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help, I tried your solution and it worked. However I need to clear my concept on the case statement inside the SUM function.

Comment: isn't the `else 0` part redundant?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think `else` part is just for making the query more understandable

Comment: @ZoharPeled The default for a `CASE` without an `ELSE` clause is `NULL`. Not quite the same as zero, but acceptable in some applications. Explicitly specifying an `ELSE` clause shows that you've pondered how you want unspecified values handled which is helpful for long term maintenance.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Not at all.  If you left it out, then the value would be `NULL` when there are no matches, and the comparison `= 0` would fail.  You could change the comparison to `is null`, but even I would find that confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use:**

```
Select visitid_fk from AEs,Yourtable Where (Youtable.visitid_fk = AE.visitid_fk) AND (AE <> 'Headache')
```

**OR**

```
Select visitid_fk from AEs,Yourtable Where (Youtable.visitid_fk = AE.visitid_fk) AND (AE Not Like 'Headache')
```

The resault All the `visitid ID`s where `AE` <> "Headache".

Comment: No, I have mentioned above about it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your solution however I only used the solution Gordon provided which is giving me correct result.

Comment: Warren, this query will return visit id 1 also, there are 2 entries for visit id 1, one for headache, another for nausea, and this visit id 1 has had headache once so I dont want this in my result.